# Incomplete(over-zoomed) image shown for box coordinates extraction using selectROI

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to opencv,
I want to draw a rectangular box and get the coordinates of the box in an image using opencv.selectROI, but the image that opened to select the area using selectROI is incomplete,
zoomed-in, because of this i'm able to see only a portion of the image.(top-left corner).

Is my image too large, is that why it is being cropped?

I did try using cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL but am not sure where to add this....!!!

The read image function using just cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL is very blurry/pixelated but complete.

Since my intention is to get the coordinates i think this could help.

Code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("path")

# Select ROI
r = cv2.selectROI("select the area", image)
print('Selected bounding boxes: ',r)
```

Comment: [mre] please. and state the size of your image, and the size (in pixels) of your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did try using cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL but am not sure where to add this....!!!

add a line like:

```
# set window flags
cv2.namedWindow("select the area", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

# Select ROI
r = cv2.selectROI("select the area", image)
```

Comment: Using this the image and squished and the coordinates no longer correct, is there a way around this?